# What is this encoding and how do I make it readable?

Tags: c#

What is this ampersand stuff and, using C#, how do I make it readable?

```
"Votre message a &eacute;t&eacute; envoy&eacute;. Un repr&eacute;sentant du Service &agrave";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is HTML Encoded text. You can use the [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx) to decode the text back to its original form:

```
string decoded = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(encodedString);
```

`decoded` should contain:

> Votre message a été envoyé. Un
>   représentant du Service à

Answer (score 1):

See [symbols](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp).  In your particular case you have a lot of

```
&eacute;
```

entries.  It means an accented E:  `É`.

I'd use [HtmlUtility.Decode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx) to decode it.

Answer (score 1):

The confusing part are HTML entities.  Basically, they start with an ampersand (&) and go to a semicolon(;).  Between them can either be text or a number.  They are used to represent characters that don't appear in the standard 7-bit ASCII character set.

If it's a text entity, like your "&eacute;", it should be easy enough to figure out.  "&eacute;" means "acute-accented e", while "à" is "grave-accented a".  Similarly, "&amp;" is ampersand (which I had to manually insert to make this display right.)